# Spark dataframe changes column values when writing on SQL server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, azure-databricks

I'm facing a very specific problem. I'm working on a pyspark notebook on Databricks. I run the following command:

```
my_df.select("insert_date").distinct().show()
```

and get:

```
+--------------------+
|         insert_date|
+--------------------+
|2021-12-22 09:52:...|
|2021-12-20 16:36:...|
+--------------------+
```

then, I run:

```
my_df.persist()
my_df.write.option("truncate", "true").mode("overwrite").jdbc(sqlDbUrl, "[dbo].[my_table]",properties = connectionProperties)
my_df.unpersist()
my_df.select("insert_date").distinct().show()
```

and get:

```
+--------------------+
|         insert_date|
+--------------------+
|2021-12-22 09:52:...|
+--------------------+
```

if I interrogate the SQL database, the result is consistent with the second show:

```
select distinct insert_date from [dbo].[my_table]

**result**
insert_date
2021-12-22 09:52:31.000
```

and this is undesired, I would like to preserve the two distinct values for column insert_date within the SQL table, and I can't get why this is not happening.

Further information:
Databricks column type: string
python version: 3
SQL column type: NVARCHAR(MAX)
There are no costraints such as default value for the SQL column

For any further information, please ask in the comments.
Thanks in advance!